# Jade - tags and plain text in one string

Tags: node.js, pug

I've started using Jade few days ago. Now I've got a simple question (briefy looked though Jade docs - couldn't find an answer).

```
h2 Welcome! Please, a(href="/login") log in.
```

generates plain text. How can I make Jade process

```
a(href="/login") log in
```

as a Jade-styled html tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it on a new line, tabbed inside the element:

```
h2 Welcome! Please, 
  a(href="/login") log in.
```